# Error while init of C++ std map with C++ Pair ON SOLARIS

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap, std-pair, solaris-10

The below code runs OK in Linux but gives compiler error in Solaris. I am trying to initialize an std pair and then using it to init a C++ Map. It runs perfectly in linux , however Solaris has got an issue with this. Any one has idea what can be done to make it OK in all UNIX variations?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

using namespace std;


std::pair<std::string, std::string> envVarsData[] =
{
        std::make_pair(std::string("HOME"), std::string("home")),
        std::make_pair(std::string("RETURNED"), std::string("Returned"))
};

size_t iSize = sizeof(envVarsData) / sizeof(envVarsData[0]);
std::map<std::string, std::string> envVarsMap(envVarsData, iSize);

int main()
{

 return 0;
}
```

The error thrown is as below

```
# CC t1.cpp
"t1.cpp", line 21: Error: Could not find a match for std::map<std::string,std::string>::map(std::pair<std::string, std::string>[2], unsigned) needed in<no tag>.
1 Error(s) detected.
#
```

Comment: `map` constructor takes a pair of iterators (e.g. pointers), not a pointer and size. Makie it `std::map<std::string, std::string> envVarsMap(envVarsData, envVarsData + iSize);`

Comment: On Solaris this still gives error as below
# CC t1.cpp
"t1.cpp", line 22: Error: Could not find a match for std::map<std::string,std::string>::map(std::pair<std::string, std::string>[2], std::pair<std::string, std::string>*) needed in<no tag>.
1 Error(s) detected.

Comment: I think the above error goes away if i compile with option as below
CC -std=c++11  t1.cpp
However, any suggestion to compile it without this option is always welcome !!!!

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/IES3565).

Comment: Did you use any specfic flag like -std=c++11
I am building in SOLARIS and unable to compile without above compile flag. The code shows NO issues in linux

Comment: Can  you share your solaris machine version. The above code fails to build on my solaris box
# uname -a
SunOS p4dev-sol10.proiv.local 5.10 Generic_147147-26 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To use C++11 features with the Solaris Studio C++ compiler, you **must** use the `-std=c++11` option.  Per [the **What's New in Oracle® Solaris Studio 12.4** guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37071/gndfg.html):

> **Using C++11 Features**
>
> In Oracle Solaris Studio 12.4, the C++ compiler supports C++11, a new
>   language and ABI (Application Binary Interface).
>
> In C++ 11 mode, the CC compiler uses the g++ ABI and a version of the
>   g++ runtime library that is supplied with Oracle Solaris Studio. For
>   this release, version 4.8.2 of the g++ runtime library is used.
>
> An ABI describes the low-level details in the generated object code.
>   Modules that use different ABIs cannot successfully be linked together
>   into a program. This means that you must use C++11 mode on all modules
>   in your program, or none of them.
>
> If you use Oracle Solaris Studio 12.4 C++ as an upgrade to Oracle
>   Solaris Studio 12.3 (C++ 5.12), no changes are needed in scripts or
>   makefiles if you are not using C++11 features. An exception is Rogue
>   Wave Tools.h++ is not available. For more information about features
>   no longer supported, see Features That Have Been Removed in This
>   Release in Oracle Solaris Studio 12.4: Release Notes
>
> **To compile in C++11 mode, add the option –std=c++11 to the CC command line.** The location on the command line is not important. The
>   option causes the compiler to recognize language features new in
>   C++11, and to use the C++11 version of the standard library (g++
>   runtime library that is supplied). Except for the options marked as
>   incompatible with –std=c++11, all other command-line options can be
>   used along with C++11, and have their usual effects. The –std=c++11
>   option must be used consistently on every CC command used in building
>   a library or executable program.

Imagine having a huge installed base of C++ code, upgrading to a new compiler, and having the default language option change from, say, C++03 to C++11 **and breaking a lot of already-working code**.

> It runs perfectly in linux

That's likely because [the default language option for g++ is GNU-extended, non-standard C++14](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html):

> The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is `-std=gnu++14`.

If you want portable code, you can't use non-standard extensions on any platform.

> Any one has idea what can be done to make it OK in all UNIX variations?

Don't use non-standard compiler extensions on *any* platform.

Yes, that means you likely have to go back and change the options on Linux, where if you are using the default `g++` options you are compiling with non-standard GNU extensions to C++.