# How to initialize std::map globally in solaris

Tags: c++, c++11, solaris-studio

For instance, I have below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef map <int, string> mapType;
mapType myMap = {{1, "One"}, {2, "Two"}, {3, "Three"}};

int main() {
   for (auto itr = myMap.begin(); itr != myMap.end(); ++itr) {
      cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second << '\n';
   }

   return 0;
}
```

It works absolutely fine in linux environment(GCC 4.8x) but in case of solaris(Oracle Solaris Studio, version 12.6) I'm getting below error.

```
Could not find a match for std::map<int,std::string>::map({initializer list}) needed in file level.
```

I have gone through the various blogs and tried to initialize map with different ways but didn't work. For example below code has resulted in same error.

```
mapType myMap {{1, "One"}, {2, "Two"}, {3, "Three"}};
mapType myMap = mapType {{1, "One"}, {2, "Two"}, {3, "Three"}};
```

I want this map to be global so that it can be accessed from different files. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878631/error-while-init-of-c-std-map-with-c-pair-on-solaris

Comment: @MarekR you are using gcc compiler, yes by removing ```=``` works fine in gcc and i have mentioned that already.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/b4hW7e3Ej